# Server explorer blocked by firewall when adding remote SQL Server database

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, windows-firewall

I have been trying for weeks to get my Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2010 to go through my Windows firewall, but what ever I do, I never succeed. What bothers me is that I know the connection works if I shut down my firewall. Then the connection works perfectly. And when I reactivate it gives me the standard:

> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that sql server is configured to allow remote connections (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

But I know it works without the firewall. I tried adding an inbound and outbound rule to Visual Studio that leaves everything open, but no good. I'm suspecting that the server explorer uses another process to contact SQL Server, and THAT process is being blocked. However this is speculation.

Any help would be nice

Comment: Have you added exceptions for SQL Server?

Comment: Do you mean the sqlservr.exe? I didn't think that was necessary since it's a remote server we are talking about. Also, it's not working.

Comment: Oh, wait... when you run your program, it's nit visual studio running. Forgot that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I get what you are talking about. This has everything to do with Visual studio. It's about the Server Explorer inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I didn't get that from the question. Sometimes I miss the obvious. Have you done any packet sniffing to see how far the connection is getting?

Comment: As far as I can see it never leaves the computer. When the firewall is deactivated the communication flows through nicely.